# Remove function in Release build only

Tags: c++

Is there any methods to remove a line of code from a Release build, but leave it in the Debug build without ugly `#if` statements?

For example, is there some way to achieve the equivalent of the below code without using all these if statements?

```
#if DEBUG
    Log.Log("I am in debug mode");
#endif
```

If I have a conditional, run-time check in the `Log.Log` function, then the string "I am in debug mode" will be preserved within my compiled executable, which is exactly what I **do not** want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define another macro in a common, shared header.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define LOG(m) Log.Log(m);
#else
#define LOG(m) do {} while(false);
#endif
```

Then replace your calls to `Log.Log` with `LOG`.

Comment: You may want to make the second define (the release version) be: do {} while(false) to properly deal with semi-colons people would be likely to add after this call. consider:if (foo) LOG(m) important_call()

Answer (score 1):

You'll ultimately need a preprocessor conditional somewhere, but you could apply it "upstream" in some shared header if you want to keep your application code clean.  In that case, you'd have something like

```
#if DEBUG
   #define DebugLog(m) Log.Log(m);
#else
   #define DebugLog(m)
#endif
```

in the header associated with `Log`, and instead of calling Log.Log(m) inside a preprocessor conditional in your application code, you'd just call `DebugLog(m)`.  In a Debug build, the macro would expand to Log.Log(m), but otherwise it would just disappear entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Have your `Log.Log` function #ifdef'd based on the build. So in DEBUG, it logs stuff, and in RELEASE, it's a no-op. For example:

```
namespace Log
{
  void Log()
  {
  #if DEBUG
    //Insert logging code here.
  #endif
  }
}
```

Comment: One small issue with this approach is that you still pay a minor performance penalty for calling the Log() function at all, even if that function did nothing.  Using a macro-centric approach let's non-Debug builds literally do nothing instead.

Comment: @adpalumbo: That assumes that the compiler/linker can't figure out that the function does nothing. Compilers tend to have some form of global optimizations these days, so they can optimize them out completely.

Comment: It would take a pretty advanced compiler to optimize it to that extent across compilation units.  It's possible that some do this, but I wouldn't rely on it.  That said, the penalty for doing what you suggest is often trivial in everyday use, and there's something to be had for just having clean C++ code instead of playing games with the preprocessor.